# Functions that are almost (left-) continuous almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0, T]$ as $\lambda(\cdot)$. Call a measurable function $f : [0, T] \to \mathbb{R}$ *almost left-continuous almost everywhere* if there exists an $A \subseteq [0, T]$ with $\lambda(A) = 0$ such that for all $t \in A^c$, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$, and $N \subseteq [0, T]$ with $\lambda(N) = 0$ such that for all $s \in (t - \delta, t] \cap N^c$, $|f(t) - f(s)| < \epsilon$.

Is there a well-known class corresponding to these functions? Is it the case that all functions satisfy this property? This class is certainly not the a.e. left-continuous functions. I am not exactly sure if this is the class of functions that are equal to a left-continuous function a.e.